# Automation for JSP Multilingualization

Tags: jsp, internationalization, automation, multilingual

An existing set of JSPs, hard-coded with English field labels, javascript error/info messages, image 'alt' message etc. needs to be multilingualized.

What would be the best way to go about converting these JSPs to use the standard Java Multilingual features (resource bundles, locales etc)?

Comment: I don't quite think that could be easily automated. You can add ResourceBundle reference to your JSP pages via simple Perl script, some messages could also be automated this way, but there is a problem with compound messages and formatting of Dates, Currencies and Numbers. I don't think you can automate it.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not too interested in dates, currency, numbers and all other 'internationalization' stuff; just the ability to support multiple languages... I guess I'd have to write something parse these files after all...

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried it, but the [Bravo JSP Editor](http://bravo.x-o.co.cc/index.php) plugin claims to be capable of this. [Here's a demo](http://bravo.x-o.co.cc/demo2.php).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking something like "gettext". This is majorly a unix based tool but you can also get a java binding here: [link text](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/)

Comment: gettext is a great i18n library, but what really needs to be done is to place the _()/i18n.tr() automatically in the jsp file.